# Replacing strings in templates in Go

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a block of variables in my templates that repeats a lot.

To fix that, i figured that i could

1. Create a unique string inside a template (like `__VARIABLE_BLOCK__`)
2. While parsing the template, replace that unique `__VARIABLE_BLOCK__` string with a predefined block of variables
3. Execute the template with the new values

Everything until the 2nd step works, but the problem is updating the actual content of the template, before it is executed.

### Current code

```
func ExecuteTemplate(t_name string, t_path string, t_funcs template.FuncMap, full_output_path string, data interface{}) {

    tmpl, err := template.New(t_name).Funcs(t_funcs).ParseFS(templates, t_path)

    const injected_variables = `
    {{ $random_var_1 := .ProjectInfo.ProjectName  -}}
    {{ $random_var_2 :=  convertToTitle .Module.ModuleName -}}
    `

    tmpl_content := tmpl.Tree.Root.String()
    replaced := strings.Replace(tmpl_content, "__VARIABLE_BLOCK__", injected_variables, -1)
    _ = replaced
    fmt.Println(replaced) // returns correct
    tmpl_content = replaced

    tmpl.Tree.Root.String() = replaced // ERROR:  cannot assign to tmpl.Tree.Root.String() (value of type string)

    out, _ := os.Create(full_output_path)
    defer out.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not parse struct template: %v\n", err)
    }

    tmpl.Execute(out, data)
}
```

There must be a way to fix this.
Help appreciated.

Comment: The program replaces text in a string representation of the template parse tree.  You must do one of the following: (1) Use  template features to insert the text (2) replace the text before parsing the template (3) replace the text in the [parse tree](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template/parse).

Comment: Templates support define, condition,loop ... structures. Maybe instead of such constants in template you would like to use define blocks?